# Returning MapView instance from async function (or passing it to promise resolver) cause a promise infinite chain

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await, arcgis, arcgis-js-api

The simple code bellow causes thousands of warning logs like this: `[esri.core.Promise] DEPRECATED: then() -- use .when(callback, errback) instead`.

**simple code:**

```
async function test() {
  const view = new MapView({
    container: "map",
    map: new Map({
      basemap: "satellite"
    }),
    zoom: 2
  });

  return view;
}
```

whitout the `return view` everything works fine.

The same thing append when passing MapView instance to a resolver, like `Promise.resolve(mapViewInstance)` or `.then(() => mapViewInstance)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somes ArcGIS JS API classes looks like promises as their instance present a `then()` method.

See https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/guide/working-with-promises/#api-classes-as-promises

If you return an instance of one of those classes of an async function (or passing it to a promise resolver), the promise will think that it actually is a new promise and will chain it, as if you would have done something like `.then(() => new Promise())`.

**solution:**

Wrap the instance in an array or an object to "hide" the `.then()` method:

`Promise.resolve([mapViewInstance])`

`Promise.resolve({mapViewInstance})`

```
async function test() {
  return [mapViewInstance]
}
```

**Initial reflexion:**

https://github.com/Esri/esri-loader/issues/101